# What are some good mobile credit card readers?

Tags: android, point-of-sale

I along with my friends are starting up a second-hand book store.

So, we want a portable mobile credit card reader, which is easy on the pocket (as we are a startup, we would be able to shell not more than $100)

As the store is a portable set-up such that it can be moved easily from a place to another place, a nice, portable and durable reader is preferred.

No issues with the compatibility, but an Android compatible device would be preferred in case of a specs tie, as most of the team members have an android device.

---

From the comments, I came to know that it is called a "**Point of Sale**" machine, just in case it might help while answering.

Comment: So, a point of sale machine?

Comment: @Zizouz212 Yes.  But, a portable one which can be plugged into a mobile phone port.

Thank you for the term. Edited the question.

Comment: Alright, I think I know of something that is compatible with both android and iOS for just about $50, but I'm at school right now so I'll see if I can post an answer during my lunch break :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend Square's [card reader](https://squareup.com/reader). You can get the magstripe reader for free from Square. This should imply to you that most of their service is on the software side. They also advertise a [contactless reader](https://squareup.com/contactless-chip-reader) for NFC and chip cards as "coming soon", though you can reserve it for free. If you don't care about the "contactless" part, they have a reader that will read the new chip cards already available for $30.

[image: Square Reader]

I have had the magstripe reader for a few years. I use it for personal payments. It's supported every Android device I've had since the OS was version 2.0. It also supports my iPad and has run just fine through all OS upgrades in the last few years.

They have [additional](https://squareup.com/shop) software related features you may find useful, though I can't vouch for any of those. These include a full PoS system, employee management, a market place and the ability to set up an online store through them.

Importantly, their [rates](https://squareup.com/pricing) are reasonable (for my limited use):

- Per swipe, sale on the Online store or Square Invoices: *2.75%*   (Swipe in $100, and you get $97.25)
- Per manually entered transaction: *3.5% + 15 cents* (Enter $100 and you get $96.35)

Both methods accept Visa, Mastercard, Discover and American Express (with the same rates). Deposits go into your bank account within two business days.

As I said above, I use my Square reader for personal things. Usually payments among friends/family. I've also used it when hosting a garage sale. I feel that was very helpful in getting rid of more "stuff", compared to previous years where I didn't use the reader. Square will email a receipt to the customer and Square protects you for a small amount of charge backs (though, I have never used this feature).

Comment: As a user from the customer side, this is a good device. It maps your email address to your card, so even if you use a different device, you will still get the receipt emailed to you.

Comment: @Cfinley And that's an awesome feature for recurring customers. Mine would be so happy!